# Controller::detect() undefined in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am getting an error message when trying to register all the controller routes in Laravel 4 (Illuminate) by adding:

```
Route::controller(Controller::detect());
```

to my `routes.php`

The error :

```
Error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Routing\Controllers\Controller::detect() in C:\wamp\www\travless\app\routes.php line 13
```

I suppose they changed the function name, but I don't know where to find it because it is still an alpha version and there is no documentation I'm aware of.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This function has been removed in Laravel 4 because of inconsistent behavior with varying filesystems. The proper way to register controllers should be to explicitly define each one you wish to use in your routes file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register each controller manualy in routes.php file

```
Route::controller('users', 'UsersController');
```

First params stands for URL to respond, second one is controller's class name

Comment: and if you want to call users/profile then it must be function named as getProfile(){} in UsersController.