# Nested Controllers in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel

I'm just giving the new Laravel 4 a try and can't seem to fathom out a way of nesting controllers. Are nested controllers still around in Laravel 4 and is so how would I route to them in my routes file?

In my Laravel 3 apps I used Controller::detect() and all my nested routes were picked up, but I understand this feature has been removed from Laravel 4?

Do I just explicitly define each Route::resource in my routes file?

Comment: Why don't you just try out?

Comment: I am trying it out, but before I explicitly define all my Route::resource's in my routes file I wanted to check if there was a better way of doing it.

Comment: So `Controller::detect()` is gone in Laravel 4?

Comment: Yeah, apparently there were some behavioral issues with it and varying file systems.

Comment: Ah, right, just seeing: [Controller::detect() undefined in Laravel 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14200516/controllerdetect-undefined-in-laravel-4) - If it did work well for you, why don't you consider to port it into 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation you do need to explicitly route each resource: http://four.laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers

Comment: With the release of the documentation for Laravel 4 this week, I've seen that this is the correct. Routes do need to be explicitly defined.

Answer (score 0):

For Brevity purposes:

> Route::controller('example', 'ExampleController');
>
> Route::get('example', array('uses' => 'ExampleController@getIndex');