# Calling controllers dynamically

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm attempting to create dynamic routing in Laravel for my controllers - I know this can be done in Kohana, but I've been unsuccessful trying to get it working with Laravel.

This is what I have right now:

```
Route::get('/{controller}/{action?}/{id?}'...
```

So I would like to call `controller/method($id)` with that.

Ideally this is what I would like to do:

```
Route::get('/{controller}/{action?}/{id?}', $controller . '@' . $action);
```

And have it dynamically call $controller::$action.

I've tried doing this:

```
Route::get('/{controller}/{action?}/{id?}', function($controller, $action = null, $id = null)
{
    $controller = new $controller();
    $controller->$action();
});
```

But I get an error message: Class Controller does not exist.
So it appears that Laravel is not including all the necessary files when the controller extends the BaseController.

If I use `$controller::$action()` it tells me I can't call a non-static function statically.

Any ideas for how to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading that Laravel doesn’t support this anymore, I came up with this solution:

```
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$results = array();
preg_match('#^\/(\w+)?\/?(\w+)?\/?(\w+)?\/?#', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $results);

// set the default controller to landing
$controller = (empty($results[1])) ? 'landing' : $results[1];

// set the default method to index
$method = (empty($results[2])) ? 'index' : $results[2];

Route::get('{controller?}/{action?}/{id?}', $controller . '@' . $method);

// now we just need to catch and process the error if no controller@method exists.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can auto register all controllers in one fell swoop:

```php
Route::controller( Controller::detect() );
```

---

If you're using Laravel 4 (as your tag implies), you can't use `Controller::detect()` anymore. You'll have to [manually register all the controllers you want to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14200516/controllerdetect-undefined-in-laravel-4).